# How kafka consumer choose consume nearest broker?

Tags: apache-kafka

I deploy a kafka cluster on three hosts.And deploy consumers on the same hosts.
How i to let the consumer consume the nearest broker's partitions.for example,`host a`'s consumer just consume the partitions which belong to `host a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka doesn't work that way. The clients will connect to all three brokers and produce and consume from all three brokers in parallel based on which nodes are currently the leader for each topic partition.